# How to use timestamps and preserve insertion order in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Is it possible yet, to preserve insertion order or set reliable timestamps in Meteor given that MongoDB doesn't guarantee to return items in insertion order if no sort is specified, a document's _id is randomly generated and setting a timestamp manually on insertion would depend upon the client's clock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest a method.

```
Meteor.methods({
  addItem: function (doc) {
    doc.when = new Date;
    return Items.insert(doc);
  }
});
```

While the client will run this locally and set `when` to its own current time, the server's timestamp takes priority and propagates to all subscribed clients, including the original client.  You can sort on `doc.when`.

We'll probably add hooks for setting timestamps automatically as part of document validations and permissions.

Comment: Note that storage of `Date` objects now works, so you don't necessarily need the call to `getTime` unless you really want to store your dates in ms.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use something like these collection hooks (https://gist.github.com/matb33/5258260), along with this fancy `Date.unow` function (which you can safely sort on even if many documents were inserted with the same timestamp):

```
if (!Date.unow) {
    (function () {
        var uniq = 0;
        Date.unow = function () {
            uniq++;
            return Date.now() + (uniq % 5000);
        };
    })();
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // NOTE: this isn't vanilla Meteor, and sometime in the future there may be
    // a better way of doing this, but at the time of writing this is it:
    Items.before("insert", function (userId, doc) {
        doc.created = Date.unow();
    });
}
```