# saving a clientside date as UTC date object into Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to save a date into meteor mongodb my challenge is as follows:
1) if i use new Date() it creates a date object in mongo DB however it saves the time as local time as javascript Date() this always comes with a timezone +0x:hours based on browser local timezone. When i retrieve this it causes havoc as i am assuming everything in my db is UTC.

2) I want to use moment js library which is great because it can represent dates in UTC properly but my challenge is how do i get mongo db to accept a moment time? The minute i use moment.format() it saves it as a string!

So how can i send a date to a mongodb insert command with a date object that is in UTC? string just dont work :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think everything you need to know about both of these questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465673/how-to-use-timestamps-and-preserve-insertion-order-in-meteor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937448/inserting-a-momentjs-object-in-meteor-collection).

TLDR:

- If you directly insert/update from the client you will store a timestamp based on the user's clock. It will still be stored as UTC, but you may or may not want to trust that the time is correct. I strongly suggest using a method for any db modifications which involve time so that the server's version of time will always be used.
- Moment objects are not serializable to a format compatible with mongodb. Use a date object and format it on the client.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response! So in a nutshell its impossible to store utc in mongo? are there any pitfalls in storing it as string?

Comment: When you store a `new Date`, it actually get stored (via [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson)) into mongo as an ISODate, which under the covers is a UTC integer timestamp. Whenever you actually look at the value (e.g. in mongo shell) it will be printed as something that looks like a string. It isn't - it's just being formatted that way. The bottom line is: use a method and `new Date` and I promise everything will be right with the world. There will also be puppies and rainbows.

Comment: It's also important to note that whenever you look at a date object in your browser's console, it will be formatted in the local timezone. It turns out this is super convenient but really unnerving when you want some assurance that you are storing the data correctly.

Comment: I am still trying to get my head around this one, but i have changed my code as you said and it is all 'puppies and rainbows'. thanks a lot. Guess i will sleep on it to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with saving dates on the client is that each client can have a different time zone, or even wrong time set. Thus the only solution is to have the date set on the server. Using a method for each insert / update is not an elegant solution.

A common practice is to modify the document inside `allow` or `deny` callback:

```
Messages.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
     ...
     doc.timestamp = new Date();
     return true;
  },
});
```

That way you ensure all documents have a compatible timestamp, and you can use usual db methods on the client.

Answer (score 0):

The Meteor community recently started an extensive document about how to use dates and times. You'll find a lot of useful information there, in addition to David Weldon's links:

> https://meteor.hackpad.com/Meteor-Cookbook-Using-Dates-and-Times-qSQCGFc06gH

However, in particular I recommend using https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync when security is not a concern. It allows you to client-locally obtain an accurate server time even if the client's clock is way off, without a round-trip to the server. This can be useful for all kinds of reasons - in my apps, I universally just use server-relative time and don't care about what the client's time is at all.